# Why I can't upgrade to vim 6.3 or above using yum on CentOS 6.0

Tags: vim, updates, centos-6

I'm trying to upgrade to vim 6.3 so I can improve my vim skills using an online vim book (http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/00.html). I'm trying to update my vim package (which is currently at version 6.2.411). why can't I upgrade ?

```
[foo@bar ~]# yum update vim-enhanced
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.nbrc.ac.in
 * epel: mirror-fpt-telecom.fpt.net
 * extras: mirror.nbrc.ac.in
 * updates: mirror-fpt-telecom.fpt.net
Setting up Update Process

No Packages marked for Update

[foo@bar ~]#
[foo@bar ~]#
[foo@bar ~]#
[foo@bar ~]#
[foo@bar ~]# yum update vim
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.nbrc.ac.in
 * epel: mirror-fpt-telecom.fpt.net
 * extras: mirror.nbrc.ac.in
 * updates: mirror-fpt-telecom.fpt.net
Setting up Update Process
No Packages marked for Update
[foo@bar ~]#
[foo@bar ~]#
```

**UPDATE:** I'll be happy to upgrade to 7.x. How can I tell my system to update/upgrade ?

Comment: Vim 6.3 was released 9 years ago: what you want to do doesn't really sound like an upgrade to me. You should install a more recent version (we are at 7.4) from sources or maybe try to update you system and, you know… keep up with your times. [The current version in Centos 6.0 seems to be 7.2.411.](http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/x86_64/Packages/)

Comment: CentOS 6.0 was released less than 3 years ago -- why they chose such an old version of vim is beyond me. I'm ok with version 7.x -- but how do I go about upgrading ? thank you.

Comment: I know nothing about CentOS beyond a few generalities, sorry. Maybe they have a wiki or some doc that could help you. Good luck.

Comment: According to [this page](http://pkgs.org/centos-6-rhel-6/centos-rhel-i386/vim-enhanced-7.2.411-1.8.el6.i686.rpm.html), the latest version in the repositories is 7.2.411. Maybe your repository lists need updating?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to stay up to date with VIM is to build from source. Last I saw even the freshly released VIM 7.4 already had 7 patches out. Those patches run to more than 1000 for VIM 7.3 and they do make a difference (sometimes) in the stability and speed of the version that you are using.

As stated on [vim.org](http://www.vim.org/mercurial.php) and on [vim.wikia.com](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Building_Vim), building VIM is not hard. The best instruction is in the README file once you have downloaded the source.

Once you have a configuration file that suits your needs, then building again after a mercurial update is even less trouble. And on Linux this really is the best way to stay up to date.